# Staggered and uneven column in GridView or RecyclerView.

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

What is the best practice to create View like this.

1. Make staggered RecyclerView.
2. Gridview
3. Custom linearLayout.

[image]

Comment: That looks like `FlowLayout`s in a `ScrollView`. Android doesn't have a built-in or support `FlowLayout`, but there are several examples on-site of how to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) library to implement staggeredGridView and add customs sections (to achieve sections like Festivals) by overriding adapter class of staggeredGridView